# Converting Java Thread processing messages to queue using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit2, messaging, kotlin-coroutines

My Android app has a dedicated thread to make network api calls using retrofit.The thread makes a retrofit api call depending on the type of the message received. I would like to migrate this code to  use Kotlin co-routines but I not sure how to implement message queues without using a Thread. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Pseudo java code:

public class MyThread extends Thread {

```
private final Messenger mPushMessenger;
private Handler mHandler;
private Object mThreadLock;
private  IMessage mMessage;


private MyThread(IMessage message) {
    super(message.getThreadLink().name());
    mMessage = message;
    start();
    mPushMessenger = new Messenger(getHandler());
    mThreadLock = new Object();
}

public static MyThread getInstance(IMessage ISenThread)
{
    return  new MyThread(ISenThread);
}

public void NotifyThreadLock() {
    synchronized (mThreadLock)
    {
        try {
            mThreadLock.notify();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}

private Handler getHandler() {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (mHandler == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

            }
        }
    }
    return mHandler;
}


public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mHandler = new MyThread().MyHandler();
        notifyAll();
    }
    Looper.loop();

}

public void pushMessage(Object message, int what) {
    try {

        android.os.Message msg = android.os.Message.obtain(null, what, message);
        mPushMessenger.send(msg);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }

}

public void EmptyQueue() {  
}


/*
public void pushMessage(String message) {
    pushMessage(message, SenFCMLink.SenEyeStatusSender.STATUS_GENERAL_MESSAGE);
}
```

*/

```
private class MyHandler extends Handler {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch(msg.Type)
        {
            case A:
                // call retrofit  API Method A
            case B:
                // call retrofit API Method B
            case C:
               // call retrofit API method C.    
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: so i am assuming that in this thread you are making synchronous network calls? post your code of this thread

Comment: updated java sample code

Comment: Retrofit methods can be declared for either synchronous or asynchronous execution,i think Retrofit not need a Thread  , .

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit methods can be declared for either synchronous or asynchronous execution

```
  call.execute();
```

is a synchronous network call ,0

Synchronous requests are declared by defining a return type.Synchronous methods are executed on the main thread. That means the UI blocks during request execution and no interaction is possible for this period. Using the .execute() method on a call object will perform the synchronous request. The deserialized response body is available via the .body() method on the response object.

```
call.enqueue()
```

is a asynchronous network call, Asynchronous requests don’t have a return type. Instead, the defined method requires a typed callback as last method parameter.Using asynchronous requests forces you to implement a Callback with its two callback methods: success and failure. When calling the asynchronous getTasks() method from a service class, you have to implement a new Callback and define what should be done once the request finishes.

like below:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
    response = response.body();
  }

 @Override
public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

}
```